# not able to unzip files in python

Tags: python

I am not able to unzip my_file.zip. It finds the correct source and target.
It is able to read and print the file component in my_file.zip. However when it reaches the following line:

```
file(os.path.join(my_dir, filename), "wb")
```

It throws an error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

`my_zip` is a component of a dynamic list.

The strange thing is that when I hard code the same list components in a test script and run the same lines of code, it works flawlessly.

```
my_dir = r"D:\Download"
my_zip = r"D:\Download\my_file.zip"
with zipfile.ZipFile(my_zip) as zip_file:
    for member in zip_file.namelist():
        filename = os.path.basename(member)
        # skip directories
        if not filename:
            continue
        #copy file (taken from zipfile's extract)
        source = zip_file.open(member)
        target = file(os.path.join(my_dir, filename), "wb")
        with source, target:
            shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
```

Please Help. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you called a variable `file` somewhere.

Comment: The correct syntax for opening a file is `open(fname, 'wb')`.

Comment: Use `open` instead of `file`.  @Paul: `file` is a synonym for `open` in old versions of python.

Comment: @cdarke Good to know. I could be wrong, but I think that multiple contexts (`with x, y`) are not supported in Python 2.6, not sure when `file` was phased out. Either way, seems like OP redefined `file`.

Comment: @Paul - my suspicion is that the code was copied from some dubious source on the inter-web.

Comment: Tried OPs code (at least the snipped from question) with python 2.7. No problems at all.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Yes I was using, file as a variable in the script. It works superb as i changed file to copy. So all of your answers are correct.
However, as I used @user2357112 answer first, I believe, he should win the credit.
Thanks to all of you again. Brad

Answer (score 1):

With python 2.7, use the following way to open a file:

```
 with open(filename, 'w'):
        #process
```

rather than using the `file` class.

It seem from your error that you have assigned a string to the name `file` earlier in the path of your code.

I highly recommend you search for the pattern `file =` in your code, and choose another name for that variable. Overriding built in names is very bad practice (and you see an example of that).

A quick and (very) dirty  work-around is to add the statement `del file` at the beginning of your code block. It will give you access to the underlying `file` class again. I do not recommend doing that though (but highlighting it as it's an interesting insight into the inner workings of python). Fixing your code is much better.